# using CodeIgniter on MAMP

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mamp, lamp

I've installed MAMP and I get the welcome page when I go to my localhost + :8888/MAMP/
But then I downloaded CI and put it in 'htdocs' inside MAMP and I can not get the CI welcome page.

I'm not very experienced with setting up servers, what should I do??

Comment: How do the .htaccess look and what error message do you see?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search returned this video tutorial on setting up MAMP, CodeIgniter and your first controller and view:

[Installing MAMP and CodeIgniter, and setting up your first controller and view](http://www.screenr.com/zj8)

That should help you get started

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but didn't work. I think he is also using an older version of CI because it does not show an 'application' folder in the CI.

Comment: @lhamhr: Have you edited the config.php to set the $config['base_url'] value? Additionally, do you have mod_rewrite enabled in your MAMP?

Comment: the video link no longer works